# Using FitText jquery plugin to resize text

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive-design

I'm trying to use the FitText jquery plugin to get resize some text. The problem is that the text only gets blown up after a window resize event.

```
// Resizer() resizes items based on the object width divided by the compressor * 10
            var resizer = function () {
                $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width()     / (compressor*10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
            };

            // Call once to set.
            resizer();
```

It looks like the script calls the "resizer" function at least once initially. Am I missing something here?

This is how I'm using the script:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("h1").fitText(.6);

</script>
</body>
```

I'm pretty new at this stuff and really just trying to throw things together so any help will be much appreciated.

***EDIT***
I should have been more specific in my description of the issue. I am attempting to utilize FitText within the caption box of a FlexSlider. I was able to get Ankit's example below to work, but the FlexSlider caption text remained incorrect. I believe that a necessary slider element is not loaded in time for FitText to take effect. I worked around this with the following awful code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#spinner').hide();
    setTimeout( function() { $("h1").fitText(.6); }, 200 );
     setTimeout( function() { $("h1").fitText(.6); }, 300 );
     setTimeout( function() { $("h1").fitText(.6); }, 500 );
     setTimeout( function() { $("h1").fitText(.6); }, 700 );
   setTimeout( function() { $("h1").fitText(.6); }, 1500 );
}); 
</script>
```

I know that must be a hack of hacks, but my text now resizes as desired. If anyone could suggest a better way, I'm all ears.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you solve it? I need some help.

Comment: I just worked around the issue using $document.ready and setTimeout as shown in my edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone's interested, you can solve this problem now using a flexslider callback like so:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animationLoop: true,
  directionNav: false,
  start: function(){$(".fittext").fitText();},
  after: function(){$(".fittext").fitText();}
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me -- the elements still resize after being visible on the page.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to add this javascript after your content loads. Trying adding the script tag before closing body tag and see if it works

Edit:
A simple example that works for me:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js/master/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is test</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $("h1").fitText(0.6);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the script is already placed just before the closing body tag. I'll edit the snippet above to reflect that.

Comment: I've updated this answer with a minimal code that works. Did you include the right version of jquery and fittext js files?

Comment: Thanks for the assist; It got me thinking in the right direction. I have updated my initial post above with additional info.

Comment: So it seems that your h1 tags don't get attached to the DOM before the request is made. Are you adding it at runtime (JS/Ajax)?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still having the issue, this fix works for me

Replace this code inside `jquery.fittext.js`

```
// Call once to set.
resizer();
```

With this code,

```
$(window).load(function(){
    resizer();
});
```